# Setting multiple items in array to disabled with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

The current process of setting multiple inputs to `disabled` works for me, but seems to be way too much code due to the multiple for loops:

```
var textEditors = document.getElementsByClassName('textEditor'),
        textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
        radioInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('radioSelect'),
        textInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < textEditors.length; i++) {
        textEditors[i].disabled = true;
    }
    for (var g = 0; g < textInputs.length; g++) {
        textInputs[g].disabled = true;
    }
    for (var f = 0; f < textareas.length; f++) {
        textareas[f].disabled = true;
    }
    for (var z = 0; z < radioInputs.length; z++) {
        radioInputs[z].disabled = true;
    }
```

But this above works fine for me. The below is what I would assume would work instead - put all elements into a single array, and iterate over a single array to set each to `disabled`. When I view the HTMLCollection via `console.log` it says `disabled:true` yet the element on the screen is not disabled. What am I missing here?

```
var textEditors = document.getElementsByClassName('textEditor'),
        textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
        radioInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('radioSelect'),
        textInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    var normalInputs = [];
    normalInputs.push(textEditors);
    normalInputs.push(textInputs);
    normalInputs.push(radioInputs);
    normalInputs.push(textareas);

    for (var i = 0; i < normalInputs.length; i++) {
        console.log(normalInputs[i])
        normalInputs[i].disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: well you're pushing array in array and applying disable on array not each element in second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will serve your purpose.**

In your second method you're pushing the array capture from `getElement` into `normalInputs` array and than looping through that array and applying disable property on elements of `inputArray` which is eventually array of all the `selected elements` not `individual element`.

```
var textEditors = document.getElementsByClassName('textEditor'),
    textareas = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'),
    radioInputs = document.getElementsByClassName('radioSelect'),
    textInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

var normalInputs = [];
normalInputs.push(textEditors);
normalInputs.push(textInputs);
normalInputs.push(radioInputs);
normalInputs.push(textareas);

normalInputs.forEach(e=>{
  e.forEach(ele =>{
    ele.disabled = true;
  })
})
```

**Without ES6**

```
for (var i = 0; i < normalInputs.length; i++) {
      for(let j=0; j< normalInputs[i].length; j++){
      normalInputs[i][j].disabled = true;
     }
  }
```

A better approach is use `concat`

```
var normalInputs = [];
    normalInputs = normalInputs.concat(textEditors,textInputs,radioInputs, textareas);

for(let i=0; i<normalInputs.length; i++){
  normalInputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Comment: It should be `ele.disabled = true`. must be a typo.

Comment: what would solution without ES6

Answer (score -1):

Well, give all of them same class like `.inputs` and get all of them with one expression:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputs' );
```

if it's not possible, get all of them like this:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll( 'input, .textEditor, .radioSelect, textarea' );
```

then you can fix that with one loop for all of them:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ )
    items[ i ].disabled = true;
```

Comment: your solution will not scale well if i have to go into a system with unlimited divs and update their class names.
i was also trying to find help specifically to my problem of my more advanced for loop not triggering which OP answered for me.

Comment: I'm not gonna discuss your reason, thanks for pointing this out at least. But just for more clarification, your question doesn't point for scalable options, in fact, accepted answer doesn't scale with unlimited divs as well.
another aspect is that funny **advanced** word, but nvm.